# Add a HTML block above each chapter header

Tags: r, bookdown

I see that we can customize the look of bookdown HTML with

```
---
output:
  bookdown::html_book:
    includes:
      in_header: style.css
---
```

and there is also `before_body` and `after_body`, as described here: https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/yaml-options.html

But I'm not sure how I can insert some text or a div that displays directly above every chapter heading in my HTML output. For example, I want an alert box that says "Warning: Early Draft" with an alert symbol and a link to another page.

Similarly, how can I insert a div directly below the bottom of the text of each section (i.e. html page)?

Can I use `includes:` or do I need to modify some kind of template? I see mention of templates in the bookdown pkg (https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/html.html#bootstrap-style), but if this is what I need to edit, then I want to have one that lives with my bookdown Rmd files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow up, I [discussed](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/265) this with the package author, who confirmed that the template was hard-coded. He kindly advised me on how this might be changed , so I [submitted a pull request](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/pull/267) to the bookdown package. And now we can use `_output.yml` to inject text and HTML just above each chapter/section title like this:

```
bookdown::gitbook:
  includes:
    before_body: xxxx.html
```

Where `xxx.html` is a HTML file containing the content to be inserted above the title.